# Python - Returning list/ arry from function

Tags: python, function, return

I am writting a small program to list the available usb devices. I have created a seperated file with function so that it can be accessed any time from other scripts. The main objective of this function is to return list/ array as output. If I use print command it successfully prints list of available devices. However, when i use return command it only retun the first detected device. I have gone through other similar question from SO but couldnot find any valid solution for this issue. Here is the code I have tried using dbus. Any help is appriciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import dbus

def find_usb(self):
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    ud_manager_obj = bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.UDisks", "/org/freedesktop/UDisks")
    ud_manager = dbus.Interface(ud_manager_obj, 'org.freedesktop.UDisks')

    for dev in ud_manager.EnumerateDevices():
        device_obj = bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.UDisks", dev)
        device_props = dbus.Interface(device_obj, dbus.PROPERTIES_IFACE)
        if device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', "DriveConnectionInterface") == "usb" and device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', "DeviceIsPartition"):
            if device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', "DeviceIsMounted"):
                device_file = device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', "DeviceFile")
                #print device_file
                return device_file

            else:
                print "Device not mounted"
find_usb("")
```

Comment: Have not used dbus but from, what I can see, with return on device_file, you are just returning on first execution and it does not let loop over all available results. Use list here and that will work. What does device_file anyway? name seems confusing. Please clarify?

Comment: device_file is the partition of the inserted usb. In the script above it is just a string. When you execute the script you get output like this "/dev/sdc1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning the *first* device you match. Build a list instead and return that list:

```
def find_usb(self):
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    ud_manager_obj = bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.UDisks", "/org/freedesktop/UDisks")
    ud_manager = dbus.Interface(ud_manager_obj, 'org.freedesktop.UDisks')

    found = []

    for dev in ud_manager.EnumerateDevices():
        device_obj = bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.UDisks", dev)
        device_props = dbus.Interface(device_obj, dbus.PROPERTIES_IFACE)
        if device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', "DriveConnectionInterface") == "usb" and device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', "DeviceIsPartition"):
            if device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', "DeviceIsMounted"):
                device_file = device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', "DeviceFile")
                #print device_file
                found.append(device_file)

            else:
                print "Device not mounted"

    return found
```

A `return` statement immediately ends the function; by putting a `return` in your loop, you exit the function *at that point* and end the loop prematurely.

The alternative is to make this a *generator function*, by using a [`yield` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) to produce your matches; you can then loop over the result of `self.find_usb()` once only, but you'll be producing device files on demand instead:

```
def find_usb(self):
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    ud_manager_obj = bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.UDisks", "/org/freedesktop/UDisks")
    ud_manager = dbus.Interface(ud_manager_obj, 'org.freedesktop.UDisks')

    for dev in ud_manager.EnumerateDevices():
        device_obj = bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.UDisks", dev)
        device_props = dbus.Interface(device_obj, dbus.PROPERTIES_IFACE)
        if device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', "DriveConnectionInterface") == "usb" and device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', "DeviceIsPartition"):
            if device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', "DeviceIsMounted"):
                device_file = device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', "DeviceFile")
                #print device_file
                yield device_file

            else:
                print "Device not mounted"

    return found
```

Generators are a more advanced technique however.

Comment: A generator would be more pythonic here.

Comment: @thg435: It would be; but I fear that might be a step too far for the OP.

Comment: I think a generator would be suitable when memory efficiency were an issue (e.g. iterating over a large collection). In this case a list is probably sufficient.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters and pjama Both of your solution worked.  I did not expect the answer to y question in few min after posting. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a list variable and append the devices to it. Then at the end of the function, return the list.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import dbus

def find_usb(self):
    devices = [] # instantiate empty list variable!
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    ud_manager_obj = bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.UDisks", "/org/freedesktop/UDisks")
    ud_manager = dbus.Interface(ud_manager_obj, 'org.freedesktop.UDisks')

    for dev in ud_manager.EnumerateDevices():
        device_obj = bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.UDisks", dev)
        device_props = dbus.Interface(device_obj, dbus.PROPERTIES_IFACE)
        if device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', "DriveConnectionInterface") == "usb" and device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', "DeviceIsPartition"):
            if device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', "DeviceIsMounted"):
                device_file = device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', "DeviceFile")
                #print device_file
                devices.append(device_file)

            else:
                print "Device not mounted"
    return devices

find_usb("")
```

Answer (score 0):

A big problem with even making sense of your code was that the logical structure was hidden in a lot of indentation. Here is a rewrite that preserves the operation of the original while allowing the structure to be seen.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import dbus

def find_usb(self):
    ofud = 'org.freedesktop.UDisks' # convenience string for brevity
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()

    ud_manager_obj = bus.get_object(ofud, "/org/freedesktop/UDisks")
    ud_manager = dbus.Interface(ud_manager_obj, ofud)

    for dev in ud_manager.EnumerateDevices():
        device_obj = bus.get_object(ofud, dev)
        device_props = dbus.Interface(device_obj, dbus.PROPERTIES_IFACE)
        dp_get = device.props.Get   # convenience method for brevity
        if (dp_get(ofud, "DriveConnectionInterface") == "usb" and
            dp_get(ofud, "DeviceIsPartition")):
            if dp_get(ofud, "DeviceIsMounted"):
                device_file = dp_get(ofud + '.Device', "DeviceFile")
                print device_file
                return device_file
            else:
                print "Device not mounted"
                return None         # implied
         else:
             return None            # implied
    return None

find_usb("")
```

Others have amply answered what the problem was, but it was not helped by the difficulty in reading. Part of that isn't your fault, the dbus interface is verbose, but there are things you can to to tame that as I did with `ofud` and `dp_get`.

The [PEP-8 Style Guide for Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and [PEP-20 The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) exist in large part to help you write code that make errors easier to see. In particular, the deep nesting of your conditionals could be cleaned up a lot:

```
if dp_get(ofud, 'DriveConnectionInterface') != 'usb':
    continue
if dp_get(ofud, 'DeviceIsPartition') and dp_get(oufd, 'DeviceIsMounted'):
     device_file = dp_get(oufd + '.Device', "DeviceFile")
     found.append(device_file)
```

Since your original code doesn't do anything with non-usb devices it is clearer to "fast fail" to the next iteration of the loop and skip an entire level of indentation. There are certainly other ways to make the intention of the code more obvious, I've just shown a few.

Readability matters.